# How to get last element in position id

Tags: php, css

How can i get the last element of that position id. it is generating all iterations so i can place a button on that last elements by applying if condition

```
$quiz = LP_Global::course_item_quiz(); 
if ( ! $questions = $quiz->get_questions() ) { 
    return; 
} 
$questions = array_values( $questions ); 
?>

<ul class="question-numbers">

<?php 
foreach ( $questions as $position => $question_id ) {
    $class = $quiz->get_question_number_class( $question_id, ++ $position ); 
?>
  <li class="<?php echo join( ' ', $class ); ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $quiz->get_question_link( $question_id ); ?>">
      <span><?php echo $position; ?></span>
    </a>
  </li>
<?php 
} 
?>

</ul>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `if ($position == count($questions)-1) {`

Comment: yes i have applied the condition but it still shows the button

Comment: Then I am not sure I understand what yo are trying to do, please try and make your intensions more clear

Comment: the class variable is made. can i include function of last position in the class variable and apply if condition after that with the help of class variable ?

Comment: <?php  
        foreach ( $questions as $position => $question_id ) {
  if ($position == count($questions)-1) { ?>
        <button type="submit"><?php _e( 'Complete', 'textdomain' ); ?></button>
        <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

You have new function in PHP7.3+ :

[function.array-key-last](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-last.php)

```
foreach($array as $key => $element) {
    if ($key === array_key_last($array))
        echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```

Or you have many ways to get the last element in a foreach loop : [Google Search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=php%20get%20last%20element%20foreach&oq=php%20get%20last%20element%20foreach&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4190j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)